# WebSocket4Net unable to connect to proxy

Tags: c#, websocket, proxy, socket.io, websocket4net

Try to connect WebSocket4Net to proxy so that can debug in fiddler. However, hit exception that the remoteEndPoint is null in Connect method in SuperSocket.ClientEngine.Proxy when trigger .Open() method.

```
var proxy = new HttpConnectProxy(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8888));
_socket.Proxy = (SuperSocket.ClientEngine.IProxyConnector)proxy;
_socket.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in SuperSocket.ClientEngine. I have sent them a [pull request](https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperSocket.ClientEngine/pull/52)